# Unable to connect redis container from my web api container in azure container instance(ACI)

Tags: docker, redis, azure-container-instances

I'm deploying my app in azure container instance (Container Group).

I've 3 docker containers

- web_api
- redis
- neo4j

I'm able to access the database by using `localhost:7474` as hostname, but can't access redis by using localhost as the hostname.
This is the same problem I'm facing when I run containers locally using `docker run` command.

NOTE: I can't use docker-compose as my intention is to use ACI.

**azuredeploy.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "containerGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "devCG",
      "metadata": {
        "description": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "name_web": "web-api",
    "image_web": "dev.azurecr.io/web-api:89",
    "name_redis": "redis",
    "image_redis": "redis:5.0.9",
    "name_neo4j": "neo4j",
    "image_neo4j": "neo4j:3.5.6"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('containerGroupName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2019-12-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('name_web')]",
            "properties": {
              "image": "[variables('image_web')]",
              "resources": {
                "requests": {
                  "cpu": 1,
                  "memoryInGb": 0.5
                }
              },
              "ports": [
                {
                  "port": 80
                },
                {
                  "port": 8080
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[variables('name_redis')]",
            "properties": {
              "image": "[variables('image_redis')]",
              "resources": {
                "requests": {
                  "cpu": 0.5,
                  "memoryInGb": 0.2
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[variables('name_neo4j')]",
            "properties": {
              "image": "[variables('image_neo4j')]",
              "resources": {
                "requests": {
                  "cpu": 0.5,
                  "memoryInGb": 0.2
                }
              },
              "ports": [
                {
                  "port": 7474
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "imageRegistryCredentials": [
          {
            "server": "dev.azurecr.io",
            "username": "dev",
            "password": "********************"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "osType": "Linux",
        "volumes": [
          {
            "name": "devfs",
            "azureFile": {
              "shareName": "dev",
              "readOnly": "false",
              "storageAccountName": "devfs",
              "storageAccountKey": "*****************************"
            }
          }
        ],
        "ipAddress": {
          "type": "Public",
          "ports": [
            {
              "protocol": "tcp",
              "port": 80
            }
          ],
          "dnsNameLabel": "dev"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "containerIPv4Address": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/', parameters('containerGroupName'))).ipAddress.ip]"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing redis over local host requires special tweaks in the redis config.

Have a look at

https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/45

And

https://github.com/luin/ioredis/issues/763

The recommandation is to connect over the redis hostname, you can nap this local up to redis hostname

Comment: As suggested in the above article and https://redis.io/topics/quickstart, I provided `command": ["redis-server", "--bind", "127.0.0.1", "--port", "6379"]`. But I'm still getting `[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
`